# AngularJS: Add Focus behavior to list items similar to `select-option`

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I have a `html` list with some text items. I need to bring the list item into focus when user type the initial letters of it's text similar to `select-option` when user type initial letter of it's options; matching option is brought into focus. I need to have same behavior for list. I am rendering my list using `ng-repeat` directive of angular:

```
<ul class="list-group m-3 col">
  <li ng-repeat="song in ctrl.songs | orderBy" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" tabindex="{{$index}}">
    <span>{{song}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I googled for a plugin/library but unfortunately couldn't find any. I can write a `directive` for this but time does not permit it. So can anyone please tell me if there's any library/plugin available? Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lcs4f1ZM7YuNwHSf78Y8?p=preview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending quality time with `jQuery` and `tabindex` of bootstrap I finally made it working.

```
function bringToFocus(text) {
        var item = element.children().filter(function(child) {
          return angular.element(this).text().trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(text.toLowerCase());
        }).first();
        item.focus();
      }
```

Here's the working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lcs4f1ZM7YuNwHSf78Y8?p=preview). Hope it might be helpful for someone.